# Thucydides with Android

Tags: android, robotium, thucydides

I'm interested if someone already tried to use thucydides for acceptance tests for android application.

It looks like we could replace WebDriver with Robotium for example.

Let me know if question is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of using thucydides but I believe from having a quick look you are going to have a lot of issues.

Basically the problem is that robotium runs on the phone and requires an android thing called instrumentation to run which you only get from extending certain classes.

This does not fit in to the way that webdriver works on android which is a test running on your machine which sends commands to a server on the phone.

Robotium is working on a new version that will work similar to webdriver and this will help you but currently this is in beta and has been for a while. What might actually be of help to you though is some projects done by some people at eBay: http://calabash-driver.github.com/

This gives a selenium like interface for you to use and will probably work as you want.

Comment: sorry for late reply, still don't have to check it. I will accept answer as soon as I finish the related spike